# Database functional dependency for Nullable Columns

Tags: sql, database, normalization, nullable

I have 4 columns in my non-decomposed, non-normalized Job Application table which are all Nullable, for example my table is:

```
Name | SSN | Education   | City | Job Applied | Post | Job Obtained | Post Obtained

John. | 123 | High School | LA   | USPS        | MailMan | USPS        | MailMan

John. | 123 | High School | LA   | Dept. of Agri        | Assistant | *null* |  *null*

Sam. | 123 | BS | NY | Intel | QA Analyst | Intel |  QA Analyst
```

The first 4 Columns are non-nullable so I can easily determine Functional Dependencies between them.

The last 4 columns, can or cannot have values depending on if a person has got a job and also depending on if he/she has applied for a job.

My question is: Can I have Functional Dependencies on Nullable Columns either them being on the LHS or the RHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be yes, please see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency